# Json comparison which contains arrays using Java

Tags: java

Json1:

```
{
  "array1": [
    {
      "Name": "Xytrex Co.",
      "Description": "Industrial Cleaning Supply Company",
      "Account Number": "ABC15797531",
      "Address": {
        "Street": "st.road",
        "pin": "789723"
      }
    },
    {
      "Name": "XYZ Company",
      "Address": {
        "Street": "Peters road",
        "pin": "789700"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Json2:

```
{
  "array2":[
    {
      "Name": "Xytrex Co.",
      "Description": "Industrial Cleaning Supply Company",
      "Account Number": "ABC15797531",
      "Address": {
        "Street": "st.road",
        "pin": "789723"
      }
    },
    {
      "Name": "XYZ Company",
      "Description": "Domestic Cleaning Supply Company",
      "Address": {
        "Street": "Peters road",
        "pin": "789700"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Java Code used by me:

```
JsonParser Parser = new JsonParser();

Object obj1 = Parser.parse(new 
FileReader("/home/cloudera/Desktop/SampleJson/src/JSON1.json"));

 Object obj2 = Parser.parse(new 
 FileReader("/home/cloudera/Desktop/SampleJson/src/JSON2.json"));

    JsonObject jsonObject1 = (JsonObject) obj1;
    JsonObject jsonObject2 = (JsonObject) obj2;


Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> entries1 = jsonObject1.entrySet();

Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> entries2 = jsonObject2.entrySet();

 for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : entries1) {
        //System.out.println("FirstJson:"+entry.getKey());
    }

 for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : entries2) {
        //System.out.println("SecondJson:"+entry.getKey());
    }

 if (jsonObject1.equals(jsonObject2)) {
        System.out.println("Success");
    } else {
        entries1.removeAll(entries2);
        //System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("Result:" + entries1);
    }
```

I have to compare two json files which contain arrays using Java, In array1   "Description" is missing I have to print that exact key and not the entire Json from first to last. In my output also "Description" is not there, but it's not printing exactly that key, its printing from first to last. Please help me with this.

The output I got:

Result:[array1=[{"Name":"Xytrex Co.","Description":"Industrial Cleaning Supply Company","Account Number":"ABC15797531","Address":{"Street":"st.road","pin":"789723"}},{"Name":"XYZ Company","Address":{"Street":"Peters road","pin":"789700"}}]]

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I have updated my used code, I couldn't print the exact key. Please help me to print the exact key.

Comment: You print a `Set` of `Map`, so you get the output you asked for..

Answer (score 0):

This library is clean way to handle json comparison. It also has compare mode like strict check etc.
http://jsonassert.skyscreamer.org/javadoc/org/skyscreamer/jsonassert/JSONCompare.html
For your usecase you can check JSONCompareResult solves your problem.

Comment: org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONCompare is this open source? If not please suggest the same kind of library in an open source.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use https://github.com/eBay/json-comparison library.
This library based on JsonAssert project but provide additional features 
such as 'Exclude paths' , dealing with order and more